# How can I rewrite URLs in Sapper? (SvelteJS)

Tags: svelte, sapper

I built already many websites with Sapper and I love it, but now I'm using it to build a multilanguage website and that's a little harder.

I think I know how to deal with the strings' translation, but I'd like to be able to translate URLs too. For example */en/about* should be */it/chi-siamo* in italian and both should use */[lang]/about.svelte*

I'm trying to override the URL on server.js but I can't make it work properly.

**This is my server.js**

```
import sirv from 'sirv';
import polka from 'polka';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';
import admin from './firebase/admin.js'

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';
const cv = customVars;

const server = polka(); // You can also use Express

if(dev) server.use(sirv('static', { dev: dev, etag: true, maxAge: 1000000, immutable: true  }));

server
  .use(
    compression({ level: 9, threshold: 1000 }),
    sapper.middleware()
  )

// only listen when started in dev
server.listen(PORT, err => {
  if (err) console.log('error', err);
});

export { sapper, cv, admin};
```

**My question:**
How can I rewrite the URL so that when the user access on /it/chi-siamo it respondes with /[lang]/about.svelte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this isn't very straightforward at the moment without doing `[lang]/[page]`. It's something we want to [address in future](https://github.com/sveltejs/sapper/issues/576) though.

You *could* do this to mutate the request on the server, though it's a little messy:

```js
const paths = {
  it: {
    'chi-siamo': 'about',
    // others...
  },
  fr: {
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};

server
  .use(
    compression({ threshold: 0 }),
    (req, res, next) => {
      const [, lang, ...parts] = req.url.split('/');
      const path = (paths[lang] || {})[parts.join('/')];

      if (path) {
        // mutate the request object
        req.url = req.path = req.originalUrl = `/${lang}/${path}`;
      }

      // let Sapper handle the mutated request
      next();
    },
    sapper.middleware()
  )
  .listen(PORT, err => {
    if (err) console.log('error', err);
  });
```

But this won't affect client-side navigation, so if the user clicks a link to `/it/chi-siamo` then the page won't be found, and Sapper will fall back to traditional server-side navigation, which isn't ideal.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made me understand where was the issue. 

My code was working server-side, but the client-side was probably feeling confused about that. I guess not just during navigation, but also when sapper was hydratating the page (IMHO).

Anyway I just remembered that I can use regex in routes..so I can just do this:

`[lang]/[about(about|chi-siamo)].svelte`

Not the best solution, but it's easier, and it should totally work if I don't need many languages.